# How to go to next activity after touching the screen exact 3 times

Tags: android, imageview, touch, multi-touch

i am very beginner to Android. There is one screen with imageview and touching exact 3 times on image, next activity should appear..

Please help me with this
Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to manage the count for the same. Do this:

```
int touchCount = 0;

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       touchCount  = touchCount  + 1;
      if (touchCount  == 3){
              touchCount=0;
              Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityA.class);
              startActivity(intent);
           }else{
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Click more"+ Integer.toString(3-touchCount) +" time to navigate next screen."),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
});
```

Comment: nice..+1 but make touch count to zero after launch the Activity for the next time coming back to the activity

Comment: either in else part or in Resume of activity we can do that

Answer (score 3):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    private int clickCount;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (++clickCount == 3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Where `MainActivity`,  is the name of your current activity, and `OtherActivity` is your target.

Comment: tnxx a ton.. its working properly.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int click = 0;

image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       click  = click  + 1;
      if (click == 3){
              click=0;
              Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, nextActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
           }
});
```